# Strange error : INVALID_FIELD, All accounts must have the same current owner and new owner.: [OwnerId]

Tags: apex, account, update

We have a scenario in which when a custom object owner gets updated we will cascade that to all accounts related to that object via a junction object.

Code is very simple.

```
if (!studentClassRoomList.isEmpty()) {
    for (AssocationJucntion__c record : studentClassRoomList) {
        Account acc = new Account();
        acc.Id = record.Student__c;
        acc.OwnerId = classRoomOwnerMap.get(record.Student_Classroom__c);
        acc.Account_Owner_Change_Bypass__c = true;
        updateAccOwnerList.add(acc);
    }
}

update updateAccOwnerList;
```

But it gives an exception:

> System.DmlException -->>> Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 0019G0000***; first error: INVALID_FIELD, All accounts must have the same current owner and new owner.: [OwnerId]

I didn't find any documentation related this. Is there official documentation from SF  related to this?

Making the transaction in Async resolves it but not sure of the root cause.

Comment: Is the junction object in master-detail with account?

Comment: @DavidCheng Yes its master detail

Comment: But the junction object does not get updated as shown above in snippet.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this seems to be a known issue for bulk account ownership changes as of the Spring '22 release: https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000gAzHXAA0/all-accounts-must-have-the-same-current-owner-and-new-owner-invalid_field-error-occurs-when-updating-account-owners-with-ownerchangeoptions-using-api

No *official* workarounds found yet as of this posting.

**EDIT**: At least for dataloader, changing the batch size to 1 clears the issue.

Comment: eh, the developer forums aren't really a great source of information, and certainly not a source for _official_ information (that, or the signal/noise ratio there is so horrible that you couldn't reliably pick out official/good information). When you said "known issue", I was expecting a link to `https://issues.salesforce.com/` rather than the developer forums. The post you link to is also from June 2018 (so about 4 years prior to Spring '22)

Comment: For apex too, making the transaction as async, `future` or `queueable` resolves this, but I was actually looking for something official, as a known issue or document, rather than developer forum.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the source Derek, I dropped in the wrong URL. Comment updated with issues.sf.com documentation

Comment: Changing the batch size to 1 worked for me.